# Why is *a{...} invalid indirect?

Tags: go

`invalid indirect of oauth.RequestToken literal (type oauth.RequestToken)`

Why is the following line invalid?

```
func (s *Service) Callback(r *http.Request, req *RequestOauth, resp *Response) error {
    c := endpoints.NewContext(r)
    consumer.HttpClient=urlfetch.Client(c)
    ====>requestToken := *oauth.RequestToken{Token:req.Oauth_token, Secret:""}<======
    b, err := TwitterApi(requestToken, req.Oauth_verifier)
    resp.Message=b.Name
    return err
}

func TwitterApi(requestToken *oauth.RequestToken, verificationCode string) (u *UserT, err error) {
    accessToken, err := consumer.AuthorizeToken(requestToken, verificationCode)
    if err != nil {log.Fatal(err)}
    response, err := consumer.Get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json", nil, accessToken)
    if err != nil {log.Fatal(err)}
    defer response.Body.Close()
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &u)
    return
}
```

Comment: the star `*` is not needed perhaps?

Comment: if i remove it, then `AuthorizeToken` from `TwitterApi` starts complaining that it needs a pointer :)

Comment: maybe `TwitterApi(&requestToken,...)`

Answer (score 123, accepted):

This line:

```
requestToken := *oauth.RequestToken{Token:req.Oauth_token, Secret:""}
```

translated literally says "create an instance of `oauth.RequestToken`, then attempt to dereference it as a pointer."  i.e. it is attempting to perform an indirect (pointer) access via a literal struct value.

Instead, you want to create the instance and take its address (`&`), yielding a pointer-to-RequestToken, `*oauth.RequestToken`:

```
requestToken := &oauth.RequestToken{Token:req.Oauth_token, Secret:""}
```

Alternatively, you could create the token as a local value, then pass it by address to the `TwitterApi` function:

```
requestToken := oauth.RequestToken{Token:req.Oauth_token, Secret:""}

b, err := TwitterApi(&requestToken, req.Oauth_verifier)
```

Answer (score 11):

You'll need to create a pointer to the value you're creating, which is done with `&` , `*` does the opposite, it dereferences a pointer. So:

```
requestToken := &oauth.RequestToken{Token:req.Oauth_token, Secret:""}
```

Now requestToken is a pointer to a oauth.RequestToken value.

Or you can initialize requestToken as a value:

```
requestToken := oauth.RequestToken{Token:req.Oauth_token, Secret:""}
```

Now requestToken is a oauth.RequestToken value.

Then you can pass a pointer to that value to TwitterApi

```
  b, err := TwitterApi(&requestToken, req.Oauth_verifier)
```

Answer (score 4):

I may add to the top answer, if we want to explicitly look at a struct value in one line we could do this :

```
*&yourStruct
```

Where you get the instance of your struct, look up at its memory address, and access its value.

Comment: didn't know you can do that :) Although I do think you don't going to see this in code because the above would be the same as just `yourStruct` example https://play.golang.org/p/DeIQ23Z4KqJ

Comment: your code just mean, value referenced on address of variable yourStruct, so it wil just the same writing yourStruct